# Python two parameters of a generic method to have the same concrete type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, static-typing

How i can to test that a parameters of function have the same concrete type?

Example:

```
class A(Generic[T]):
   def __init__(p: T):
       self._p = p

   def get_data(self) -> T:
       return self._p

class B(Generic[T]):
   def __init__(p: T):
       self._p = p
   
   def inc(v: A[T]):
       self._p = self._p + v.get_data()

class I(Generic[T]):
   def __init__(a: A[T], b: B[T]):
       self._a = a
       self._b = b

   def execute():
       self._b.inc(a)
```

Ok:

```
I(A(1), B(2)).execute()
```

Failed:

```
I(A(1), B("2")).execute()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do, and specifically how the example does not already satisfy what you want?

Comment: I want to check a error kind like def f(p1: Callable[[T], T], p2:Callable[[T], T]). If f called as like f(p1[int], p2[str])

Comment: Can you please stop changing the use-case? A function is something different than a ``Generic`` class. In specific, a ``Generic`` has *custom* variance whereas a function has pre-defined variance.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i just want to show a more exactly example, to avoid a confusions. I don't a change it anymore.

Comment: So what would you expect? That `I(A(1), B("2"))` does typecheck?

Comment: Yes, if i accidentally wrote something like this, i want to see warnings from typechecker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to me it looks  like you want to use type variables / generics? That is, when a function is called, that type variable is then bound for that particular call.

For example, we could have a function `head()` which optionally returns a head item of a homogenous list (Python doesn't have this restriction for lists, but for now imagine we want to have):

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Optional, List

T = TypeVar("T", int, float, str)


def head(lst: List[T]) -> Optional[T]:
    if lst:
        return lst[0]
    return None


print(head([1, 2]))
print(head(["koi"]))
print(head([]))
```

Now, any of str, float or int are allowed types for these lists, but they
must be homogenous. So the type signature basically says that  "head takes list of strings, ints or floats, and whatever the type of the items is in the list, the return value (if present) will be of that type too"

Note that this is quite different from union types, eg. you could have

```py
T = Union[str, float, int]

def head(lst: List[T]) -> Optional[T]:
    ...
```

but it wouldn't then work like you want; according to types, returning an int would still be ok even if list contained only strings.

**Update**: as kindly mentioned by @MisterMiyagi in the comment below, this still requires user to be aware of types that are allowed.

For your use case (with classes), this should be fine (trying to use minimal example):

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class A(Generic[T]):
    def a(self, a: T, b: T) -> T:
        return a


print(A[int]().a(1, 2))
print(A[float]().a(32.1, 2))
print(A[str]().a("koi", "bar"))
# print(A[int]().a(1, "bar")) -- does not pass type checker
```

Crucial difference here is that you still need to pass types when you actually call them, but they don't need to be present when you define your generic class.

Check out https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html for more information on those.

Comment: But if the function take a two parameters? I want to check that those parameters have a same types and if it isn't case then to see an error from mypy or pycharm

Comment: That's true. To be fair I don't know how to mimic eg. Haskell
 type class definition of ```head:: [a] -> Maybe a``` here

Comment: Ok i changed my example, maybe it's be more understandable

Comment: Would it now satisfy the original need?