# What type annotation should I use to type a function that accept a type T and a value of that type using typing in Python?

Tags: python, generics, types, annotations, typing

I never really used Generics in the past and this is my first time using mypy in Python, but I'm trying to type a function that both accept a class and a value of that class using the typing module

So far I made this, but in both uses, `mypy` does not raise any error when I use the command `mypy file.py`. Am I doing something wrong ?

```py
# file.py
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Any


T = TypeVar("T")

def function(cls: Type[T], inst: T) -> bool: 
    # Should be true for all values matching the type annotation
    return isinstance(inst, cls) 


function(int, 5) # Correct
function(str, 5) # Incorrect - mypy should be raising an error here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When determining which type `T` is actually bound to, `mypy` looks at *both* arguments and choose a type that will satisfy each, rather than trying to use one to restrict options available for the other. When you call

```
function(str, 5)
```

`mypy` choose to bind `object` to `T`: this works because `5` is an instance of `object` and `str` is a subclass of `object`.

I don't think there is a general solution to this. For more specific cases, you can enumerate a list of types that *can* be bound to `T`, which can prevent a too-general superclass from being chosen. For example, given

```
T = TypeVar('T', str, int)
```

only `str` or `int`, not `object`, can be bound to `T` when typechecking `function`. This means the following are OK:

```
function(str, "5")  # T ~ str
function(int, 5)  # T ~ int
```

but this is not:

```
function(str, 5)  # Neither T ~ str nor T ~ int satisfy the type hints.
```

---

To force you to think about what restrictions you really want to put on `T` to disallow `function(str, 5)`, consider the following:

```
function(int, True)
```

Do you want that to fail? If so, you are violating a fundamental tenet of type checking, which says you can use a value of type `a` anywhere a value of type `b` is expected, as long as `a` is a subtype of `b`.

Do you want that to succeed? Then you need to figure out why binding `T ~ int` is acceptable but binding `T ~ object` is not. I'm not sure you can do that, again, without violating the fundamental tenet stated above.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost exactly another question asked here:

[Python two parameters of a generic method to have the same concrete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63281952/python-two-parameters-of-a-generic-method-to-have-the-same-concrete-type)

I haven't been able to replicate what the person in the answer did. They might've used a different version of python. The code is as follows, from @EdvardM,

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class A(Generic[T]):
    def a(self, a: T, b: T) -> T:
        return a


print(A[int]().a(1, 2))
print(A[float]().a(32.1, 2))
print(A[str]().a("koi", "bar"))
# print(A[int]().a(1, "bar")) -- does not pass type checker
```

I was not able to replicate this result, it seemed to pass the type checker for all of mine.

I think it's possible that what you're looking for isn't actually doable in python - it seems like you're trying to reference the type of a variable before it is fully processed by the function. Regardless, look at the aforementioned link for a more thorough answer.

Comment: This is not a related problem as they use Generic inside a class where I am trying to use only a function / method if possible. In fact, I would like to have a direct access to the given type, and I don't think this is possible using a generic given the fact that mypy giving me an error (`"T" is a type variable and only valid in type context`) if I try to use `self._type = T # with T being the Generic type` inside a method based on a Generic.